# Show only the current Week

Tags: google-sheets

I am working with Google sheets, and the Form responses that get poured into it. I am wondering if there is a way to show the CURRENT work week? What I mean by this is a sheet that shows this Friday:

`MONDAY  TUESDAY  WEDNESDAY THURSDAY FRIDAY 
 124     123      193       --       234
 344`

But then the next Monday:

`MONDAY  TUESDAY  WEDNESDAY THURSDAY FRIDAY
 088     --       --        --       --`

Is this possible, or is it to much for google sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible. To begin with, I would put dates under Monday, Tuesday, etc: this simplifies subsequent computations, and is also helpful when reading the data. This would go under "Monday": it returns the Monday of the current workweek:

```
=today()-weekday(today())+2
```

Here +2 compensates for subtraction when the date is Monday (which is numbered 2). The other days of the week can be obtained by adding 1 to Monday (`=A2+1`), or directly by using `=today()-weekday(today())+3` and so on.

Then you can pull data from the form sheet using functions such as `query`, `filter`, `vlookup`, ... For example, this formula returns the 3rd column from Form Responses 1 where the date is nearest to the content of A2 (current Monday)

```
=vlookup(A2, 'Form Responses 1'!A:A, 3)
```

A possible issue here is that Form Responses record both date and time, so the "nearest" record may be from 11:50pm of previous day. One way to solve this is to use `filter`:

```
=filter('Form Responses 1'!C:C, floor('Form Responses 1'!A:A) = A2)
```

This returns all C column entries from the form where the *date* in the A column matches the content of A2.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot!